# How to decode a cookie secret, set using Connect's cookieSession?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am setting a cookie using Connect's `cookieSession()`. This seems to encrypt the cookie's secret value, returning something like 's:j:{}.8gxCu7lVJHVs1gYRPFDAodK3+qPihh9G3BcXIIoQBhM'

How do I decrypt the cookie's value?

Example code:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.get('/setcookie', function(req, res, next){
    res.app.use(express.cookieSession({ key: "test", secret: "test" }));
    console.log(req.cookies.test);
    res.end();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.cookies.test);
    res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... you seem to be a bit confused about the use of cookie sessions.

1. Your `/setcookie` path doesn't set any cookie/session values. To use a cookie session, you need to set some values on `req.session`, for example `req.session.message = "Hi there!"` These values are now stored in the cookie.
2. You can't `res.app.use()` in just one callback, the request session won't work anywhere else this way. To read those cookies in another request, put the `app.use(express.cookieSession({ key: "test", secret: "test" }));` at the application level.

Edit: Actually I've thought about your res.app.use() call and it could break your app / cause memory to leak by adding more and more middleware layers (cookieSession) to your app, each time someone requests `/setcookie`. If you want to only add the cookieSession middleware in specific requests, you need to do the following:

```
yourParser = express.cookieSession({ key: "test", secret: "test" });
app.get('/', yourParser, ...);
app.get('/setcookie', yourParser, ...);
```

## Solution

This is the actual fixed source:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({ key: "test", secret: "test" }));

app.get('/setcookie', function(req, res, next){
    req.session.message = "Hellau there";
    res.end();
});
```

Now to inspect those values, in `app.get('/',...)` try this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.session); //Yay, this will be available in all requests!
    res.end();
});
```

## Debugging

And to answer the question of how to manually decode what's stored in a cookie, look in `connect/lib/middleware/cookieSession.js`:

```
// cookieParser secret
if (!options.secret && req.secret) {
  req.session = req.signedCookies[key] || {};
} else {
  // TODO: refactor
  var rawCookie = req.cookies[key];
  if (rawCookie) {
    var unsigned = utils.parseSignedCookie(rawCookie, secret);
    if (unsigned) {
      var originalHash = crc16(unsigned);
      req.session = utils.parseJSONCookie(unsigned) || {};
    }
  }
}
```

It takes `req.cookies[key]` (basically what you've been doing already (`req.cookies.test`)), pops it into `utils.parseSignedCookie` and pops that into `utils.parseJSONCookie`.

I put your raw cookie string into the utils.js file at the end:

```
var signed = exports.parseSignedCookie(
    's:j:{}.8gxCu7lVJHVs1gYRPFDAodK3+qPihh9G3BcXIIoQBhM'
  , 'test');
var parsed = exports.parseJSONCookie(signed);
console.log(parsed);
```

and ran that. Guess what I got:

```
{}
```

Why? Because you never set anything on the `req.session` object. :)

Comment: Utils here was some kind of Node.js module?

Comment: It was a part of the `connect` `cookieSession` source code back then.