# Using cookieSession to authorize user using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, session-cookies

I am using socket.io's authorize method( In detail [here](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth)) to check whether the user is authorized to use my app by checking the cookie associated with the user.

The above blog post is fairly straight forward but I am using cookieSessions to store session data in cookies. One good question is on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709991/how-to-decode-a-cookie-secret-set-using-connects-cookiesession) but I can't figure that out.

I want to know how to decrypt cookieSession data to access the session data. A bit of my sample code:

```
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {

//Check cookie for session data

accept(null, true);});
```

In other words, how can I access the cookieSession in socket.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following (with passport, but it doesn't matter):

```
io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
    var getCookieSession = require('./lib/cookie_session');
    var session = getCookieSession(data.headers, {
        key: 'YOUR KEY',
        secret: 'YOUR SECRET'
    });

    if (session.passport.user) {
        accept(null, true);
    } else {
        accept(null, false);
    }
});
```

and getCookieSession is the following module:

```
var connect = require('connect');

var cookieParser = connect.cookieParser;
var cookieSession = connect.cookieSession;

module.exports = function(headers, opts) {
    var key = opts.key || '_session';
    var secret = opts.secret || '';
    var req = { headers: headers, originalUrl: "/" };
    var res = { on: function() {} };
    var next = function () {};

    cookieParser(secret)(req, res, next);
    cookieSession({ key: key })(req, res, next);

    return req.session;
};
```

Comment: I found the answer to this long ago. Someone had made a gist on github which worked like a charm.